# Desktop overlay program showing CPU, HDD, etc. stats

Tags: software-rec, monitoring, desktop-environment

In different screenshots of people's Linux desktops, I've seen different apps that overlay the desktop with information about their computer. Often this gadget/app shows CPU and HDD information. Sometimes it has network and temperature information as well. I've seen these a lot but they often have different looks and different information.

What program does this? Is it built-in to any Linux distribution?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I use [conky](http://conky.sf.net) to display date, battery, cpu, ram and swap information. You can find my conky file [here](http://github.com/crazymaik/configs/blob/master/conkyrc) or take a look at a thread about conky configs in the [arch-linux forum](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=39906). There you find many different configs and screenshots of conky in use.

Comment: Great. That's exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I use the [conky-colors](http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php/CONKY-colors?content=92328) theme/scripts for one of my desktops. It's a fairly user-friendly way to begin with conky.